# Select Distinct or Group By for all but one column

Tags: sql, performance, group-by, duplicates, distinct

So Im stumped at the approach I need to take. have a query here:

```
    select type_type,
        RCD_REASON,
        rc.description,
        MATERIAL_ID,
        USERID,
        DATETIME_SCRAPPED,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        TRIMDATE,
        SUBSTR(SALES_ORDER,3,8) || '-' || SUBSTR(SOL_LINE_NUMBER,3,4) AS SalesOrder,
        QTY,
        COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID 
from WORKCELL.history hh 
inner join WORKCELL.reason_codes rc
  on hh.rcd_reason = rc.reason
where rc.type_type in ('FAB','TRM') AND TO_CHAR(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(:FromDate,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(:ToDate,'YYYYMMDD')
order by 1,2,9
```

Thats pulling records based off two date parameters in SSRS. However, the problem is that I do not want duplicate records for SALES_ORDER or ORDER_NUMBER. I realize I can't use Select Distinct for my current query because technically they are all distinct based off the DATETIME_SCRAPPED because it also includes the time. What would be the best way to organize this query to get all the rows I specified, and no duplicates based off the two columns?

Comment: you can do a `max(datetime_scrapped)` or `min(datetime_scrapped)` or you can take the time off and group by/distinct the date part.  if you want to include the field, but just one of the possible values for it, there has to be some way of choosing which one you want to be returned...

Comment: So would I keep the Select statement I have and add Distinct? And as far as datetime_scrapped, just use min or max to upper or lower level time?

Comment: if you use min or max, you need to group by any column that is not in the min or max (which are aggregate functions).  I'm gonna post an answer but it will be incomplete b/c I don't have enough info yet... I assume you might have issues with other columns, too.

Comment: I think I follow you. Unfortunately, they want to keep the time on there, so I would have the go the MIN/MAX Route. So how about rewriting the query like: (Ill Post in the answer section)

Comment: post the data that you have and post an example of the data you want....

Comment: Just posted it on the answer

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Shameless Bump for Help

Comment: if you show me the table schema for `history` and `reason_codes` I can give you an exact query

Comment: @gloomy.penguin We use name-value pairs to minimize creating so many tables. The Schema for either is very verbose and contains alot of data not very significant in this query (At least in my feeble minded brain)

Comment: I was wondering about which fields in the select belong to which table.

Comment: All the fields will come from a history table which includes all the sales orders, materials, etc... of everything. The Query to build that into a table called History is huge, because it pulls from all our value streams. I don't know why they did it that way, but they felt that was the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually solved using window functions (you didn't specify your DBMS, but this is ANSI standard SQL supported by a wide range of DBMS).

```
select *
from (
    select type_type,
           RCD_REASON,
           rc.description,
           MATERIAL_ID,
           USERID,
           DATETIME_SCRAPPED,
           ORDER_NUMBER,
           TRIMDATE,
           SUBSTR(SALES_ORDER,3,8) || '-' || SUBSTR(SOL_LINE_NUMBER,3,4) AS SalesOrder,
           QTY,
           COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID , 
           row_number() over (partition by  material_id, order_number order by DATETIME_SCRAPPED desc) as rn

    from WORKCELL.history hh 
    inner join WORKCELL.reason_codes rc
      on hh.rcd_reason = rc.reason
    where rc.type_type in ('FAB','TRM') AND TO_CHAR(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(:FromDate,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(:ToDate,'YYYYMMDD')
) t
where rn = 1
order by 1,2,9;
```

Through the `order by` in in the window definition (the `partition by` part) you can control which row you want to return if there are multiple with the same material_id and order_number. Using `order by DATETIME_SCRAPPED desc` results in picking the "latest" based on the `DATETIME_SCRAPPED`

Comment: I am using Oracle. I will try this query out.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be something like?

```
   select type_type,
        RCD_REASON,
        rc.description,
        MATERIAL_ID,
        USERID,
        (MAX)DATETIME_SCRAPPED as DATETIME_SCRAPPED,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        TRIMDATE,
        SUBSTR(SALES_ORDER,3,8) || '-' || SUBSTR(SOL_LINE_NUMBER,3,4) AS SalesOrder,
        QTY,
        COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID 
from WORKCELL.history hh 
inner join WORKCELL.reason_codes rc
  on hh.rcd_reason = rc.reason
where rc.type_type in ('FAB','TRM') AND TO_CHAR(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(:FromDate,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(:ToDate,'YYYYMMDD')
Group By  type_type,
        RCD_REASON,
        rc.description,
        MATERIAL_ID,
        USERID,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        TRIMDATE,
        SalesOrder,
        QTY,
        COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID 
order by 1,2,9
```

The results I get in SSRS look like this, Below this table is how I would like it to look.

```
       QTY Fabric/Pc      Cut For When                Prd Ord      Sched    Sales Ord     Name 
>        1 906700021-5F72 T500173 09/30/2014 07:36:37 001038881084 20140929 05594568-4170 rg 
>        2 906700021-5F72 T500173 09/30/2014 06:22:12 001038881084 20140929 05594568-4170 rg 
>        2 906700021-5F72 T500175 09/30/2014 02:04:07 001038881052 20140929 05594568-4210 rg 
>        1 906700021-5F72 T500175 09/30/2014 10:45:42 001038881052 20140929 05594568-4210 rg 
>        1 906700021-5F72 T500176 09/30/2014 07:13:45 001038881057 20140929 05594568-4240 rg
```

I would like it to only return this:

```
       QTY Fabric/Pc      Cut For When                Prd Ord      Sched    Sales Ord     Name 
>        1 906700021-5F72 T500173 09/30/2014 07:36:37 001038881084 20140929 05594568-4170 rg 
>        2 906700021-5F72 T500175 09/30/2014 02:04:07 001038881052 20140929 05594568-4210 rg 
>        1 906700021-5F72 T500176 09/30/2014 07:13:45 001038881057 20140929 05594568-4240 rg
```

In the second data set, rows that have the same Prd Ord and Sales Ord, have been removed and the most recent time is used for the duplicate row.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?  work history with reason codes... i'm not even sure which table order information would be coming from?

Comment: I am not so much worried about reason codes and the order by at the bottom, the most important thing would be the grouping, or distinct.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin I have posted a table on how I'd like to information be grouped.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Sorry, it doesn't seem to produce those results because thats how the data is presented in my SSRS report. Let me run the query in our system. Its Oracle.

Comment: your desired results are not possible... look at the first two rows.  if the `TY` column was the same, it would be different.  how do you choose what `TY` value is returned?

Comment: the QTY is how much Cuts of Fabric there are. If there are 5 different orders with the same Fabric and various QTY, I want all that data. However if they have the same Production Order and Same Fabric number, then it is a mistake/duplicate.

Comment: okay.... and by mistake/duplicate.. you mean in the actual database, the information is stored more than once, right?  not meaning that your query just returns it more than once for some reason..?

Comment: so... for the first two lines, they have the same production order and the same fabric, but different quantities.  for the desired output, you chose the quantity 2.  why and how did you determine that?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Hey, I havent reviewed your answer but I see its detailed and in depth, Im sure it is what I am looking for, so thanks :), but to provide more insight, Yes, its stored in a database, an Oracle Database to be more exact. As far as determining the QTY, based off the Production Order and Sales order that are identical, the query to pick the most recent time of the two, and whatever qty it is, would be the one that remains. In this case, 2.

Comment: for my query below, you would use `max` instead of `min` then... to get the most recent.  it needs a few changes... i'm on my way to work right now.  i'll update in a couple hours or so.

Comment: Alright, Ill try to work with the syntax myself based off the information you have given me. Ill be looking forward to the update if I run into a rut.

Answer (score 0):

you probably don't need all the conditions in the join statement... just the date and unique id fields... try not to join on strings if you can.  I don't have time to sort it out right now, though.

```
create table history (
   history_id    int auto_increment primary key, 
   fabric_pc     varchar(20), 
   cut_for       varchar(20),
   prod_ord      varchar(20),
   sales_ord     varchar(20),  
   quantity      int,
   datetime_scrapped datetime 
);

insert into history (history_id, fabric_pc, cut_for, datetime_scrapped, prod_ord,  sales_ord, quantity) values (null,'906700021-5F72','T500173','2014-09-30 07:36:37','001038881084','05594568-4170',1);
insert into history (history_id, fabric_pc, cut_for, datetime_scrapped, prod_ord,  sales_ord, quantity) values (null,'906700021-5F72','T500173','2014-09-30 06:22:12','001038881084','05594568-4170',2);

insert into history (history_id, fabric_pc, cut_for, datetime_scrapped, prod_ord,  sales_ord, quantity) values (null,'906700021-5F72','T500175','2014-09-30 02:04:07','001038881052','05594568-4210',2);
insert into history (history_id, fabric_pc, cut_for, datetime_scrapped, prod_ord,  sales_ord, quantity) values (null,'906700021-5F72','T500175','2014-09-30 10:45:42','001038881052','05594568-4210',1);

insert into history (history_id, fabric_pc, cut_for, datetime_scrapped, prod_ord,  sales_ord, quantity) values (null,'906700021-5F72','T500176','2014-09-30 07:13:45','001038881057','05594568-4240',1); 


select   max_dt_tbl.*, history.quantity 
from     history 
         join (select   fabric_pc, cut_for, prod_ord, sales_ord, 
                        max(datetime_scrapped) as max_datetime_scrapped
               from     history 
               -- put where conditions here 
               group    by fabric_pc, cut_for, prod_ord, sales_ord
               ) as max_dt_tbl
            on history.fabric_pc = max_dt_tbl.fabric_pc and 
               history.cut_for   = max_dt_tbl.cut_for   and
               history.prod_ord  = max_dt_tbl.prod_ord  and
               history.sales_ord = max_dt_tbl.sales_ord and 
               history.datetime_scrapped=max_dt_tbl.max_datetime_scrapped
```

returns...

```
+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------+
| fabric_pc      | cut_for | prod_ord     | sales_ord     | max_datetime_scrapped | quantity |
+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------+
| 906700021-5F72 | T500173 | 001038881084 | 05594568-4170 | 2014-09-30 07:36:37   |        1 |
| 906700021-5F72 | T500175 | 001038881052 | 05594568-4210 | 2014-09-30 10:45:42   |        1 |
| 906700021-5F72 | T500176 | 001038881057 | 05594568-4240 | 2014-09-30 07:13:45   |        1 |
+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------------------+----------+
```

because...

```
mysql> select * from history;
+------------+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
| history_id | fabric_pc      | cut_for | prod_ord     | sales_ord     | quantity | datetime_scrapped   |
+------------+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
|          1 | 906700021-5F72 | T500173 | 001038881084 | 05594568-4170 |        1 | 2014-09-30 07:36:37 |
|          2 | 906700021-5F72 | T500173 | 001038881084 | 05594568-4170 |        2 | 2014-09-30 06:22:12 |
|          3 | 906700021-5F72 | T500175 | 001038881052 | 05594568-4210 |        2 | 2014-09-30 02:04:07 |
|          4 | 906700021-5F72 | T500175 | 001038881052 | 05594568-4210 |        1 | 2014-09-30 10:45:42 |
|          5 | 906700021-5F72 | T500176 | 001038881057 | 05594568-4240 |        1 | 2014-09-30 07:13:45 |
+------------+----------------+---------+--------------+---------------+----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

let me know if this is what you were going for... (according to the data I used...)

- row 1 and 2 are the same except for datetime and quantity.  row 1 is more recent so it is returned.
- row 3 and 4 are the same except for datetime and quantity.  row 4 is more recent so it is returned.
- row 5 does not have any competing rows so it is returned.

Comment: I'd like to display the most recent row for Prod_Ord and Sales_Ord row's QTY. so in terms at looking at rows 1 and 2 on the temp table, I want the first row with QTY (which is 1) because it is the most recent.